# Tkinter causes SIGSEGV and system crash - how to fix?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, segmentation-fault

I'm developing a Tkinter GUI for a python project. Everything was fine yesterday, but today my mac immediately crashes (back to log-in screen) when I run the `mainloop()` command.

I've tried to isolate the issue by cutting back GUI features, but nothing helped. The problem even occurs with the simplest of GUIs.

I'm using this demo code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")


root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run the last line, my screen goes black for a second and returns the MacOS log-in screen. Also happens when running the script from terminal. After a few repeats, I found this line to recur in the system.log after at each crash:

```
Jul 29 17:58:51 MacBook-Pro-myname com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.WindowServer[1510]): Service exited due to SIGSEGV | sent by exc handler[1510]
```

The handler number is unique to each crash. Booting in Safe Mode resolves the issue, but of course I cannot live in Safe Mode forever :)

It seems some sort of internal issue, as the python code could not be simpler. I have no clue how to debug this, can anyone help me out?

FIXED IT - For some reason Tkinter started to mess with my machine. Update to 8.6.9 resolved the issue. (see: https://bugs.python.org/issue34927)

Comment: do you run it in terminal/console `python script.py` or you use IDE/IDLE/editor to run it?

Comment: Edited the question to include the answer to yours!

Comment: I was seeing the exact same thing with Python 3.7.4. and Tk 8.6.8. For me solution was downgrading Python to 3.7.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out for some reason the standard version of Tkinter (8.6.*) was no longer functioning correctly. I found https://bugs.python.org/issue34927 and soon after updated to Tkinter 8.6.9 (conda forge), which seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (for a long time I have to use a linux machine to run my script). However, you can potentially solve the problem with 
`conda install -c zeus1942 tk` 
this is the Tkinter 8.6.10 latest version as the time I comment. It solved my problem, but not always.