# Is the tkinter 8.6 system crash bug in OS Mojave fixed in mac OS Catalina?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, shell, tkinter

I'm encountering some bug that crashes the mac OS Mojave version 10.14.6 and `tkinter` version 8.6 and causes a restart after running anything with `tkinter`

**example**:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter._test()
```

**Os crash happens ...**

```
  [Restored Oct 9, 2019 at 10:57:47 AM]
Last login: Wed Oct  9 10:56:14 on console
Restored session: Wed Oct  9 10:56:07 EET 2019
```

**And here's another form of crashing:**

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> top = tkinter.Tk()
>>> 2019-10-09 11:09:33.898 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.899 python[931:20734] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-10-09 11:09:33.905 python[931:20734] HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
2019-10-09 11:09:33.905 python[931:20734] port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
```

I tried running the same 2 lines in safe-mode, it's working perfectly fine. The question is: I'm considering to upgrade to OS Catalina, has anyone tried using tkinter on Catalina and can confirm whether the problem is gone or persists? And if it persists, are there some work arounds? I searched here and several other websites did not find a working solution. Have I missed something? I'm upgrading to Catalina either way, I'm just asking to know whether to keep trying to find a work around or just forget about it and go with the OS upgrade that might fix everything.

Comment: Apple currently recommends not upgrading to Catalina.

Comment: Because of instability issues? or something else? and do you know any work arounds for the `tkinter` thing?

Comment: https://www.forbes.com/sites/ewanspence/2019/10/08/apple-macos-catalina-broken-update-mac-imac-macbook-pro-fix-mistake/#30d7a3951035

Comment: As for the crash.. I've been having some tkinter+Mojave issues too, which I managed to fix by [downgrading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257661/tkinter-causes-sigsegv-and-system-crash-how-to-fix#comment101369311_57257661), but YMMV.

Comment: Just read the same Forbes article. I've been trying to eliminate 32 bit apps from my MacBook but some people still haven't released 64 bit versions of the software. I was bitten by the tkinter issue so I'm pretty wary about upgrading to Catalina until a few million others have tried it.

Comment: There is a comment on this Anaconda thread I've been following that tkinter didn't crash on Catalina beta but caveat emptor. If you've got no 32 bit apps and aren't a DJ you could give it a whirl and let us know...

Comment: Most probably i'll upgrade and check to confirm and stop making theories. And @Junuxx the Catalina is officially released btw, i'm not talking about the beta.

Comment: @bullseye: Neither am I.

Answer (score 1):

If using Anaconda, Installing tk 8.6.10 like this:

```
conda install -c zeus1942 tk
```

did the trick for me (MacbookAir 2016, Mojave 10.14.6)

I've read the problem is fixed on Catalina, but haven't tried it myself because a lot of sources don't recommend upgrading to Catalina.